# Why is the following function's performance not penalized by growing an additional object?

Tags: r, performance, memory-management

Below I have three functions that perform the same operation - duplicate a given data.frame and `rbind` it to itself (i.e. the bad practice of growing an object).

The first function, `f1`, copies the input object to a new object, `x`, then grows that object, and finally replaces the input object.

The second function, `f2`, copies the input object to a new object, `x`, then grows the input object.

The third function, `f3`, only grows the input object.

I would have expected `f1` to be the slowest given that it essentially requires that the memory allocation is changed for both `df` and `x`. To the contrary, all 3 functions seem to be approximately equivalent in their computation time. How can I understand this behavior? Is my example flawed?

```
## Functions
# copy df, grow copy, replace df with copy
f1 <- function(df){
  x <- df
  x <- rbind(x, x)
  df <- x
  return(df)
}

# copy df, grow df
f2 <- function(df){
  x <- df
  df <- rbind(df, x)
  return(df)
}

# grow df
f3 <- function(df){
  df <- rbind(df, df)
  return(df)
}


## Benchmark
df <- rbind(iris)
res <- microbenchmark(f1(df), f2(df), f3(df), times=5000L)


## Print results:
print(res)

# Unit: microseconds
#   expr    min      lq     mean  median      uq       max neval
# f1(df) 255.66 263.591 292.6851 270.123 292.516  2693.291  5000
# f2(df) 255.66 263.591 302.5159 270.590 292.516 15460.876  5000
# f3(df) 255.66 263.591 299.6157 270.122 292.516  3613.758  5000


## Plot results:
boxplot(res)
```

[image]

Comment: Considering that R functions are evaluated in a temporary environment, the memory allocation would be new for all three functions, wouldn't it?

Comment: @LAP - Yes, I thought about that, but even in that case there should be the issue of growing the objects.

Comment: @chinsoon12 - I'm not seeing a difference, even using `df <- matrix(runif(1e6), 1e3, 1e3)` (`times=100L`).

Comment: I think @LAP comment is relevant. You are not calling the function recursively but each function N times.

Comment: But you are growing an object in all three functions? I fail to see the difference in the operation. R does not care which object you grow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R functions use copy-on-modify.
So, when you pass `df` as an argument, if you don't modify it, it will point to the same object that you passed (same address).

Same happens if you assign to the same object. 
For example, using `address <- function(x) cat(data.table::address(x), "\n")`:

```
> x <- 1
> address(x)
0x58164b8 
> y <- x
> address(y)
0x58164b8
```

So now, printing some addresses within your functions

```
## Functions
# copy df, grow copy, replace df with copy
f1 <- function(df){
  address(x <- df)
  address(x <- rbind(x, x))
  address(df <- x)
  return(df)
}

# copy df, grow df
f2 <- function(df){
  address(x <- df)
  address(df <- rbind(df, x))
  return(df)
}
```

Result:

```
> df <- rbind(iris)
> address(df)
0x543e378 
> res1 <- f1(df)
0x543e378 
0x5d3bd08 
0x5d3bd08 
> res2 <- f2(df)
0x543e378 
0x5c89e40
```

So, each of your functions is creating only one new object, this is why they have the same footprint.